# some files and folders are missing in unity desktop

Tags: files

These are regular files / folders.  I cannot predict what folders or files will become missing on the unity desktop.  However, files and folders do show inside the HOME Folder -> Desktop.  This appears to be a very bad bug as though Unity doesn't want people to put icons on the desktop!   I'm talking about regular files, NOT hidden files or anything.  In fact, if I want to make all hidden files folders to appear from the HOME folders, how do I do that?

Here, another person has the same issue and answer remains unanswered.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/216969/files-and-folders-do-not-appear-on-the-unity-desktop

The more I use unity, the more frustrated I get.  whose dumb decision to remove the command prompt shortcut by default?? now I have to use control alt t.

Debian doesn't have any of these problems.  why is ubuntu released in such buggy condition??  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Ubuntu Tweak**.

> > > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
> > >       sudo apt-get update
> > >       sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak

Go to Tweak>Desktop>Desktop Icons. Make sure you are using the latest version.

Hope this helps. :)